# Capture href links with async method (crawler) problem

Tags: c#, asynchronous, web-crawler

My problem is that I have no result with this function. In fact, in my csv file or in my list I have no values. I spotted that the problem came from the line : if (htmlDocument != null && htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")?.ToList() != null).
It says me that the DocumentNode is empty. Do you have any idea ?

```
public class LiensHtml
    {
        public List<string>? Links { get; set; }
    }
public async Task StartCrawlerasync(string url)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
            var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);
            var All_Links = new LiensHtml();
            var writer = new StreamWriter("Tous_les_Liens.csv") ;
            var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ;

            HtmlNode test = htmlDocument.DocumentNode;

            Console.WriteLine(test.ToString());

            if (htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]").ToList() != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode link in (List<HtmlNode>)htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]").ToList())
                {
                    All_Links.Links.Add(link.Attributes["href"].Value);
                    csv.WriteHeader<LiensHtml>();
                    csv.WriteRecords(link.Attributes["href"].Value);
                };

                foreach (string lien in All_Links.Links)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(lien);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("C''est vide");
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried without the class LiensHtml in created a list of string in the Task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you could give the site you are using, but I think:

```
htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").ToList()
```

should do the trick.

Edit:
After getting the site, I've rewritten your code:

```
public class LiensHtml
{
    public LiensHtml()
    {
        Links = new List<string>();
    }

    public List<string>? Links { get; set; }

    public async Task StartCrawlerasync(string url)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
        var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

        var linkList = new LiensHtml();
        var writer = new StreamWriter("Tous_les_Liens.csv");
        var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        var links = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("link").ToList();


        if (links.Count() != 0)
        {
            foreach (var link in links)
            {
                var linkValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", "no link");

                linkList.Links.Add(linkValue);

                csv.WriteHeader<LiensHtml>();

               await csv.WriteRecordsAsync(linkValue);
               await csv.FlushAsync();
            }

            foreach (var lien in linkList.Links) Console.WriteLine(lien);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C''est vide");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this your command and this : htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("a[@href]").ToList() and it doesn't work

Comment: The link of the website is this : https://techna-ruminant2.6tmgroup.com/

Comment: I misspoke, I'm only looking to retrieve href to other html pages stored in <a> tags. On the link I sent you, I want to retrieve only the link to "Mot de passe oublié"

Comment: I'm only getting the login page so I cannot help you without a sample Html doc. I would suggest that you debug code using break statements and see what actually Html looks like and maybe you will be able to see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Yeah i understand, thank you for your help

Comment: I'll let you know if I find a solution

Comment: After an hour of search, i find that the problem is the Loadhtml : ```htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);```

Comment: How is that a problem? I think that you are trying to use a crawler on site that needs authentication, but you don't provide one, so you are on the login page.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am looking to do. I need to make a crawler for each page of the site including the login page. But by inspecting with google, we can see that on the button "Mot de passe oublié" a href link is present is the one I'm looking to retrieve. Unfortunately, my document node that I created is empty, there is only #document.

Comment: If you want i sent screenshots in an answer

Comment: Look into innerHtml property - there you can find html site you are getting from client (open it as a text).

Comment: Yeah but this is a react app